# Does VictoriaMetrics have some way to store string value instead float64?

Tags: go, prometheus, victoriametrics

I'm using basic victoria metrics via docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/victoriametrics/victoria-metrics/ and import the float value via prometheus:

```
curl -d 'foo{bar="baz"} 123' -X POST 'http://localhost:8428/api/v1/import/prometheus'
```

I saw from the victoriaMetrics code that after parsing the value is always float64, but maybe we have some way to store the errors that occurred for example?

Additional question:
After reading this one https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md#text-based-formatI didn't understand which prometheus type is stored in victoriaMetrics when we're using /api/v1/import/prometheus? Untyped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but maybe we have some way to store the errors that occurred for example?

Unfortunately, no. You can put string values into labels, but metric value will be only float64.

> which prometheus type is stored in victoriaMetrics when we're using /api/v1/import/prometheus? Untyped?

While the exposition format for metric type exists, neither Prometheus nor VictoriaMetrics do [make use of it](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/) yet. You can skip all the comments when importing in VM for now. But this may change in future.